# How to safely include server credentials with iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, security, basic-authentication, networkcredentials

I have an iOS app that connects to a server periodically looking for data updates.  The connection uses SSL and HTTPBasicAuthentication.

What is the best way to include my servers logon credentials with the app?  From my understanding, a jailbroken iPhone could read my build files and easily see the username and password to log into my server.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: If you need to secure your app even on jailbroken devices then I think all bets are off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to secure this totally.  The best you can do is to obscure it somewhat (perhaps an encrypted file that you decrypt in the app) and then monitor the server for what looks like traffic not from the app.

If you wanted to be sneaky encrypt the authentication data and then use some kind of stenography - embed the credentials in an image, or even as raw data in a file that looks like  something else (like an SSH key).

But a jailbroken developer will always be able to hook into your application to see the results of parsing that out, or possibly run an SSH proxy to simply monitor everything you are sending.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Any quick ideas as the best way to do what you suggest here 'then monitor the server for what looks like traffic not from the app.'

Comment: Basically just look for calls that omit parameters you know the app would send, try to add other parameters, or have a large volume of traffic from a single IP. There are a lot of possible ways to try and detect non-app use of the service.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "Jailbreak" your app to read the URLs. A simple packet sniffer software on your Mac will do it. Route all iPhone traffic through the Mac's Wifi and sniff it. 
But, the main question here is, Why?

If you are protecting data, you should do it securely. If you are hard coding username/password in your app in some plist, there is something wrong somewhere.

Checking for updates needn't be secure, where as the real data access should be secure. If you are downloading data for a In App Purchase, validate it against the IAP receipt. If you are downloading data for a user who has an account with your service, then password is obviously entered by him, which cannot be "sniffed" by packet sniffers if you use proper cryptographic methods.